# Multi threaded programme - design considerations

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

This might be quite complex so sorry for the wordy question.

1) Im going to redesign my application now to work with multiple threads (Backgroundworkers to be precise.) I will probably be having 5 or 6 bgw's for a particular gui. My first issue is, i have one method call that a gui needs to get its "core" data. Various parts of this data is then used for various other calls to places which also forms data that is displayed on the same page as the core data. How can i process this with various background workers such that backgroundworker1 does the core data getting, backgroundworker2 uses a particular item of the core to get more data, backgroundworker3 uses some core data and so on? Thus leaving my gui and main thread in an unlocked state

2) As i said previously, the gui has to get a set of core data first and then a fair few other database calls to get the rest of the important data. As i have seen i need to get this data outside of the gui constructor so there arent such big demands when the gui is created. In a design sense, how should i construct my gui such that it has access to data that then just needs to be displayed on creation opposed to, accessed and then displayed?

I hope these arent too wordy questions? I can see already that a lot of this comes down to programme design which as a novice is quite difficuly ( in my opinion of course). Hopefully someone can advise me as to what they would do in this situation.

Thanks

Comment: what do you gain from going multi-threaded? As you describe it, seems that your software is **synchronous** and **sequential**, i.e. the gui  sends a request, waits for the response, sends some more requests etc. Where the multi-threading comes in? Do you multiple clients talking to the data server? In some case multi-threading can even slow you down as there is overhead of locking.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good task for a work queue. The main idea behind this is to add a work item to the queue, and this work item will have an associated function to do work on the data. The work is typically distributed to any number of threads you specify.

Several of these exist, just google for it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the .net 4 Task Parallel Library? [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

Check out the area titled Creating Task Continuations almost halfway down the page.

This is an example form the linked site

```
Task<byte[]> getData = new Task<byte[]>(() => GetFileData());
Task<double[]> analyzeData = getData.ContinueWith(x => Analyze(x.Result));
Task<string> reportData = analyzeData.ContinueWith(y => Summarize(y.Result));
getData.Start();

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\reportFolder\report.txt", reportData.Result);
```

//or...

```
Task<string> reportData2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetFileData())
                                        .ContinueWith((x) => Analyze(x.Result))
                                        .ContinueWith((y) => Summarize(y.Result));

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\reportFolder\report.txt", reportData.Result);
```